# How to migrate my local neo4j dataset to the grapheneDB instance

Tags: neo4j, graphenedb

I am currently working on a project and It's time for me to host both the application and my graph database. I have chosen heroku and I have been able to deploy my application, add an add-on (GrpaheneDB). Now I would like to migrate my local dataset on my online database. I have been searching for two days now.

Every time I try restoring the database, I get this error: [image: Found attached the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from GrapheneDB's [troubleshooting section](https://docs.graphenedb.com/docs/importing-and-exporting-databases#section-troubleshooting) for importing:

> When a restore process fails, it’s usually due to one of the following
>   reasons:
>
> - The store files were copied while Neo4j is still running: Make sure
>     Neo4j is stopped.
> - The store files correspond to a newer version of
>     Neo4j than the one on GrapheneDB: Make sure you restore to the same
>     version or higher.
> - The compressed file is not a supported format: Make
>     sure you use one of our supported formats, which include zip, tar,
>     cpio, gz, bz2 and xz.
> - There are store files missing within the
>     compressed file: Make sure the archive contains the full graph.db
>     directory and all files inside (use the recursive option when creating
>     the archive).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to fixed my problem. I believe it was because of the fact that the version of neo4j I used for the graphenedb was too old. So I removed it and used the version 3.3.2. And it worked. Thank you very much.